# Is it currently possible to create my own persona IDP?

Tags: identity, browserid, persona

I'm interested in using mozilla persona/browserid in my site. Logging in with it already works pretty well. But I also want to act as an indentity provider for users that want to create an email adress with my domain.

I have implemented a very basic http server using node.js & express, that handles /.well-known/browserid requests to provide the public key and the paths to the provisioning & authentication page. But if I visit 123done.org and try to login with me@mycustomdomain.com, it says me that persona does not know this email and offers me to create an idendity.

My server never gets a request at mycustomdomain.com/.well-known/browserid, so persona never tries to really log me in using my server.

This leads me to the question: Is persona even able to log people in using thirdparty IDPs or is mozilla's the only one that works at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third-party identity providers do work today. You can find out more in the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Persona/Implementing_a_Persona_IdP) and in [these](https://lukasa.co.uk/2013/04/Writing_A_Persona_Identity_Provider/) [two](http://rfk.id.au/blog/entry/persona-identity-provider/) blog posts from people who have successfully written their own IdPs.

Question for you: Is your IdP exposing the `.well-known/browserid` support document over HTTPS? Are you using [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)?

Comment: Yes, everything is available over https. And since I host multiple domains on the same server, I also use SNI. The whole server runs on node.js. So, either there's a problem with nodes https implementation, or persona does not accept StartSSL certificates..

Comment: well, I checked it. persona does not even connect to my server :/ Maybe, persona fetched .well-known/browserid once and now caches it, but how can I clear personas cache?

Comment: And if you are still running into problems, feel free to ask for help on [our mailing list](https://www.mozilla.org/about/forums/#dev-identity) or on `#identity` (`irc.mozilla.org`).

Comment: Thanks for the link. checkmyipd.org does request my server while persona itself does not. It currently does not work, but at least I can check it through checkmyidp.org at the moment :)